# Express / Handlebars - Cannot access request object

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I can't seem to figure to this out, I've had this working in the same format before, help would be greatly appreciated!

**API Request**

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    behance.get({
        api: Behance.APIS.GET_USER_PRODUCT,
        params: { //or simply behance.get('user',
            user:'nolanwagner'
        }
    }, function (error, result) {
        if (error)
        console.log(error)
        else
        res.render('index', { data: result });
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

**Handlebars Template**

```
{{#data}}
<h1>hi</h1>
{{this.name}}
{{/data}}
```

I expect this to iterate over the data, but it only gives me just one "Hi" and no data. **This is my data object.**

```
{
   "projects":[
      {
         "id":72316151,
         "name":"Lost Leaf Cannabis Business Card Design",
         "published_on":1541613239,
         "created_on":1541613209,
         "modified_on":1541613239,
         "url":"https:\/\/www.behance.net\/gallery\/72316151\/Lost-Leaf-Cannabis-Business-Card-Design",
         "slug":"Lost-Leaf-Cannabis-Business-Card-Design",
         "privacy":"public",
         "fields":[
            "Branding",
            "Graphic Design",
            "Illustration"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an array of objects so try the "each" iterator:

```
{{#each this}}
  <p>{{this.name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```